# Wrong namespace for my webservice response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, namespaces, soapui

I'm facing an issue while calling a Webservice. The name of my Element for my response is not the same as the name in the WSDL. However for the request, it works perfectly.

Do you have any idea about this?Differents names looks fine to me.

This is the WSDL :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="test-existence-muna-service"
   targetNamespace="http://www.fimasys.com/fsb"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns="http://www.fimasys.com/fsb"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.fimasys.com/fsb">
            <element name="TestExistenceMuna_Input_Message">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" name="muna" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="TestExistenceMuna_Output_Message">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" name="existenceMuna" type="boolean"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </types>

    <message name="TestExistenceMuna_Input_Message">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:TestExistenceMuna_Input_Message"></part>
    </message>
    <message name="TestExistenceMuna_Output_Message">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:TestExistenceMuna_Output_Message"></part>
    </message>

    <portType name="testExistenceMunaPortType">
        <operation name="getExistenceMuna">
            <input message="tns:TestExistenceMuna_Input_Message" />
            <output message="tns:TestExistenceMuna_Output_Message" />
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="testExistenceMunaBinding" type="tns:testExistenceMunaPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="getExistenceMuna">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fimasys.com/fsb/getExistenceMuna" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="test-existence-muna-service">
        <port binding="tns:testExistenceMunaBinding" name="testExistenceMunaPort">
          <soap:address location="http://0.0.0.0:8088/fsb/test-existence-muna-service/"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

This is the request in SoapUI :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fsb="http://www.fimasys.com/fsb">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fsb:TestExistenceMuna_Input_Message>
         <muna>07282166.12</muna>
      </fsb:TestExistenceMuna_Input_Message>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the response in SoapUI :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getExistenceMunaResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.fimasys.com/fsb">
         <existenceMuna>true</existenceMuna>
      </ns2:getExistenceMunaResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Isn't your response element just referenced as `getExixtenceMunaResponse` somewhere in wsdl? Can you show your wsdl file?

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I edited the original post.

Comment: do you also have access to implementation? isn't there some wrapper or something what causes element to be renamed?

Comment: Well, the method called is just like
    @WebResult(name = "existenceMuna")
    public Boolean getExistenceMuna(@WebParam(name = "muna") String muna) throws FMSException;

Comment: how are you creating that WS? Contract first or code first? Are you using some framework? If you rename method name will something change?

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are having doubt regarding the prefixes in the request and response ie., `fsb` vs `ns2`, right?

It does not matter what prefix is used as long as it is using the same *namespace*. If you look at both request and response both are point to *namespace* i.e., `http://www.fimasys.com/fsb`.

You may read more about namespaces [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

Comment: Ok thanks for that. My real problem is the WSDL, my response is set to be a <element name="TestExistenceMuna_Output_Message"> but soapui gives me a <ns2:getExistenceMunaResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.fimasys.com/fsb"> instead... The input is OK by the way, in WSDL and soapui it is <fsb:TestExistenceMuna_Input_Message>